# How can I compile MySQL Control Center (mysqlcc)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm hoping this is an easy question for you C++ programmers.

I need to compile the MySQL Control Center source. Can someone please give me any advise on how to go about this?

OS: Win 8.1 (64bit)

**Tried:**

> Updated the mysqlcc.pro file
>   created a .dsp using QT (5.3.1 & 4.8)
>   opened .dsp in visual studio 2013 (error: file has been corrupted)
>   opened .dsp in visual c++ 6.0 (win xp) (error: makefile not generated by developer studio)
>   tried mingw32-make (error: missing separator: stop)

This program is from 2006/2007 so I'm wondering what programs+versions I need to get this compiled.

The compilation instructions just state:

> qmake -t vcapp -o mysqlcc.dsp mysqlcc.pro
>   Open the newly created file `mysqlcc.dsp' in Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysqlcc/ says this "Please note that development of MySQL Control Center has been discontinued." Why you don't try MySQL workbench instead?

Comment: MySQL workbench seems completely overkill. MySQL control center keeps things quick and simple